# Not able to change BIOS Settings and unable to boot through USB

Tags: boot, 17.10, bios, settings

i am not able to change BIOS setting after installing `ubuntu 17.10`
and also i am not able to install any Distro using USB beacause my USB not display in boot menu.

Comment: The OS doesn't and cant change the Basic Input Output System  / BIOS .. what system .. is it an old BIOS or the newer UEFI .. if so did you set up your UEFI as recommended . If anyone here is going to be able to help we need more information than "I don't know how to access my bios/uefi"

Comment: boot menu?  i don't know what you mean, but I'm guessing the bootloader 'grub' menu which was likely installed with 17.10.  It's too late in the process and can't** offer to boot another OS for install as this should be chosen by BIOS in its menu (ie. boot order), or pressing a fn key (F9 for  this dell when its displaying the dell logo) which lets me select the device to boot (but even this can be turned off by a setting inside of BIOS)  { **yeah it's possible, but a lot of work that's machine dependent [ie. manual]  and a lot of trouble for very little benefit)